# Find $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{3n+1}$ for $x$ in $]-R,R[$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is about finding the summation $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{3n+1}$ for $x$ in $]-R,R[$. It comes from an exercise. The exercise has two questions as follow:

> 1) Let $f:t\mapsto\dfrac{1}{1+t^3}$.
>
> (a) Give the series expansion of $f$ at $0$. Give the convergence
>   radius of this series.
>
> (b) Find $a,b$ and $c$ that satisfy 
>   $$f(t)=\dfrac{a}{t+1}+\dfrac{bt+c}{t^2-t+1}.$$
>
> (c) Calculate the primitive $F$ of $f$ such that $F(0)=0$.
>
> (2) Deduce the value of
>   $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{3n+1},$$ for $x$ in
>   $]-R,R[$

In my work I did this:

1)

(a) $$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nt^{3n},$$
and $R=1$.

(b) $a=1/3$, $b=-1/3$ and $c=2/3$.

(c) $$F(t) = 1/6\left(-\ln(t^2-t+1)+2\ln(t+1)+2\sqrt{3}\tan^{-1}(\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}})\right)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{18}$$

Now I can't do (2).

Comment: Try integrating the series expansion of $f(t)$. Remember to try seeing how the different parts of the question come together.

Comment: Hint $F(t) =\int f(t)dt=\sum_1^{\infty}(-1)^n\int t^{3n}=\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} t^{3n} $

Comment: So I have to calculate $F(\sqrt[3]{x})$ ?